how to get a python request json response that is multiple layers deep?
I have a Python request that returns a JSON, but I am struggling on how to access the deep data, the JSON is sent back like so:

{"ticket":{"custom_field":[{"id": 341434334343125, "value":
454425424}, {"id": 452452432445, "value": 53653635463}]}}

There is more to the response, but that is the structure, I need to be able to see if the
ticket["custom_field"]["id"] = 341434334343125

then grab that id's value.
I have tried tons of ways, but it always seems to lead back to:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Can someone lay it out to me? My brain has met it's match today!
This is one of many different attempts:
Code
r1 = response.json()
ticket = r1["ticket"]["custom_fields"]
    for key, value in ticket:
    print(key["id"])



Assuming in r1 is your decoded Json response from the question you can do:
r1 = {
    "ticket": {
        "custom_field": [
            {"id": 341434334343125, "value": 454425424},
            {"id": 452452432445, "value": 53653635463},
        ]
    }
}

to_find = 341434334343125

for d in r1["ticket"]["custom_field"]:
    if d["id"] == to_find:
        print(d["value"])
        break
else:
    print(f"id={to_find} not found")

Prints:
454425424


Andrej, Thank you, this was it! Unfortunately they wont let me give an add to the positive feedback because I dont have 15 reps yet. But much appreciated.
